# MVC Client Cache for Static content is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, clientcache

I've added below one in web.config

```
<staticContent>
   <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="10.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

But I'm not seeing expires on response headers. Should I do any other changes?

[image]

Comment: While I'm testing local it is not showing. It is showing after deployed in test server.

Answer (score 1):

I would try two things to debug. First I would change cacheControlCustom from `private` to `public`

```
<location path="Content">
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache 
             cacheControlCustom="public" 
             cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" 
             cacheControlMaxAge="10.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

If that does not work check the location of your path covered for caching. Your example is not showing that part.

Lastly, try to unlock StaticContent section of machine config via:

```
appcmd unlock config /section:staticContent
```

Here is a link with some additional useful information [Client Cache](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache).